# Ruby Hash not working API - Colon

Tags: ruby

I am trying to query an api through JSON / REST using Ruby.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'


###Request Build#####
url = 'http://site_name'
request ={
     "format"=>'json',
     "foo"=> {"first"=>1.1,"second"=>2.2},
     "foo_1"=>300,
     "foo_2"=>"speed",
     "foo_3"=>[
         {"id"=> "abc123", "first"=> 1.8, "second"=> 2.8},
         {"id"=> "abc456", "first"=> -1.5, "second"=> 1.2}
         ]
}.to_json

### go go go ###
response = RestClient.post(url,request, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
puts response
```

The above works, it will query the api just fine. However the API documentation I am using says I should have ":" instead of "=>" like this

```
     "format":'json',
     "foo":{"first":1.1,"second":2.2},
     "foo_1":300,
     "foo_2":"speed",
     "foo_3":[
         {"id":"abc123", "first":1.8, "second":2.8},
         {"id":"abc456", "first":-1.5, "second":1.2}
         ]
}
```

when I do use them I get this error:

```
new.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
     "format":'json',
```

I was wondering why this was? Does ruby not like hashes with ":" ? The reason I ask is that on foo_3 I have a json file I would like to put in that is formatted like:

```
     [{"id":"abc123","first":1.8, "second": 2.8},
     {"id":"abc456","first":-1.5, "second": 1.2}]
```

So when I try and use it also get the:

```
new.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
```

There are around 2000 id's - so I cant change all : to => manually and this will be dynamic as well. So I am a little stuck!

SO either I have to find a way to change all ":" to "=>" before I send the array or, I am doing something stupid and very wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the new hash syntax from Ruby 1.9. These two forms are identical

```
{foo: 1, bar: 2}
{:foo => 1, :bar => 2}
```

After formatting to JSON, symbols become strings, so

```
{foo: 1, bar: 2}.to_json
{:foo => 1, :bar => 2}.to_json
{"foo" => 1, "bar" => 2}.to_json
```

all produce the same output.

Summary: don't bother changing your hashes to the new syntax. It's working just fine.

#### Update

I just re-read your question and noticed that you mention a "JSON file" that you want to insert into ruby hash. I don't know what code you use for this, but it's not gonna fly. JSON spec requires quoted key names, and Ruby hash syntaxes (both of them) are **not** JSON-compatible. So you can't just take some JSON and pretend that it's a Ruby hash. You can parse it, though.

```
require 'json'

json_string = "{\"id\":\"abc123\",\"first\":1.8, \"second\": 2.8}"
ruby_hash = JSON.parse json_string
# {"id"=>"abc123", "first"=>1.8, "second"=>2.8}
```

#### Update 2

Since ruby 2.2, there is a third variant of hash syntax which IS json compatible. So you can take a json string and simple eval it.

```
json_string = '{"id":"abc123","first":1.8, "second": 2.8}'
eval(json_string) # => {:id=>"abc123", :first=>1.8, :second=>2.8}
```

Don't eval it, though. If it's a JSON string, use `JSON.parse` on it.

Comment: thank you that makes sense, in my file however I have quoations around each key in the hash i.e. "id","first","second" - how do i remove these so ruby will accept it?

Comment: yep that works, but my source data is coming in as "id":"222","first":222,"second":222 - so I need to conver that to id:"222",first:222,second:222 other wise i get the error - dont i?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is from Ruby `1.9` version(not sure), but anyway syntax should be as following,

```
 > [{id: "abc123",first: 1.8, second: 2.8},{id: "abc456", first: -1.5, second: 1.2}]
 => [{:id=>"abc123", :first=>1.8, :second=>2.8}, {:id=>"abc456", :first=>-1.5, :second=>1.2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it right.  the `to_json` method takes care of the formatting for you.

```
>> require 'json'
=> true
>> request ={
?>                   "format"=>'json',
?>                   "foo"=> {"first"=>1.1,"second"=>2.2},
?>                   "foo_1"=>300,
?>                   "foo_2"=>"speed",
?>                   "foo_3"=>[
?>                         {"id"=> "abc123", "first"=> 1.8, "second"=> 2.8},
?>                         {"id"=> "abc456", "first"=> -1.5, "second"=> 1.2}
>>                       ]
>>   }.to_json
=> {"format":"json","foo":{"first":1.1,"second":2.2},"foo_1":300,"foo_2":"speed","foo_3":[{"id":"abc123","first":1.8,"second":2.8},{"id":"abc456","first":-1.5,"second":1.2}]}
>>
```

Comment: thanks, yes that works but my data in foo_3 is coming in as ":" not "=>" - so "id":"abc123" etc..